# Need help on solidity compiling

Tags: compilation

**I am not getting expected files after:** `yarn add solc`.
*But the command works with some warning.*

```
yarn add v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
warning No license field
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ solc@0.8.17
info All dependencies
└─ solc@0.8.17
Done in 2.25s.
```

It is saying **Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.**,but i created a new project folder and did not use npm a single, still it is giving same error, additionally i can not see any package-lock.json file in my folder, so how can i delete it! Please help.

**INFO:** I installed yarn with npm, is it the reason?
I don't know why my corepack is not working ( nodejs installed from snap ), so i used npm for intalling yarn.

**My files after running the command:**`yarn add solc` -->

[image]

Comment: You are just adding solc as dependency. If you want to compile the contract use a framework like hardhat, it is much easier that trying to learn solc if you haven't used node before

Answer (score 0):

Hi I meet the same problem, and you can refer there to get the answer https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/203
Or you can just use this command:

```
yarn init -y
```